# Error with class causing a few hundred errors

Tags: c++, class, sfml

My header for my class is

```
#ifndef _CENGINE_H
#define _CENGINE_H
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "CTextureManager.h"
#include "CTile.h"

class CEngine
{
private:
    //Create instance of CTextureManager
    CTextureManager textureManager;
    //Load textures
    void LoadTextures();
    //New tile
    CTile* testTile;

    bool Running; //Is running?
    sf::RenderWindow* window; //Create render window
public:
    CEngine(); //Constructor
    int Execute(); //Execute
    bool OnInit(); //On intialization
    void GameLoop(); //Main game loop
    void Render(); //Render function
    void Update(); //Update
};
#endif
```

Now the 3 errors it's giving me with this are:

> cengine.h(8): error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'CEngine'. Did you forget a ';'?
>
> cengine.h(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>
> cengine.h(8): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

I know the errors are obvious but I can't see a problem with the class. I'm probably being really stupid because I'm tired.

Comment: Look in the earlier header files you include, chances are you forgot a semicolon in one of them.

Comment: The problem is most likely in code you didn't show. Most likely culprit is either CTile or CTextureManager. Check these headers for a missing `;`

Comment: Would that actually effect it that much though? I thought it would just give me one error for that telling me I forgot it.

Comment: Wow surely enough it was just that. To me it looked like all the errors were directed from the CEngine header because they needed that to be initialized. I actually forgot a semi colon on the last square bracket of the CTile header. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that the preprocessor just replaces the `#include` directive with the actual contents of the included file, so from the actual compilers view it's a single file where it sees one closing brace followed by the keyword `class` without a semicolon in between.

Comment: Compilers try to be helpful. When they find an error, they make an assumption about what the correct code should have been, and then continue to check the rest of the code. That way, when there are multiple independent errors, you don't need to re-run the compiler each time just to find one error on each run. But when the assumption is wrong, it can lead to more errors being reported about otherwise correct code. As you gain experience, you'll learn to recognize which errors are real and which are just side effects of previous errors. (Multiple errors on one line are usually just one error.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a circular include issue. Do `CTextureManager.h` or `CTile.h` include each other or `CEngine.h`?

To solve this, use forward declarations where possible. For example, your class doesn't need to include `CTile.h` - it can look like:

```
#ifndef CENGINE_H
#define CENGINE_H
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "CTextureManager.h"


class CTile;    //forward declaration instead of include

class CEngine
{
private:
    //Create instance of CTextureManager
    CTextureManager textureManager;
    //Load textures
    void LoadTextures();
    //New tile
    CTile* testTile;

    bool Running; //Is running?
    sf::RenderWindow* window; //Create render window
public:
    CEngine(); //Constructor
    int Execute(); //Execute
    bool OnInit(); //On intialization
    void GameLoop(); //Main game loop
    void Render(); //Render function
    void Update(); //Update
};
#endif
```

Similar for the other 2 headers.

Also, `_CENGINE_H` is not a valid identifier - note how I renamed it to `CENGINE_H`.

Comment: He can't forward declare CTextureManager.

Comment: @the.malkolm and neither did I. He can forward declare CTile though.

Comment: _CENGINE_H is not a valid identifier? how come? It's not standard usage but he can perfectly use that.

Comment: It's okay I got the problem. It was a semi colon that I forgot in CTile.h though I didn't think it would print errors for CEngine.h

Comment: @revani the standard forbids an identifier starting with an underscore and followed by a capital letter.

Comment: @user1816388 it's illegal regardless of whether it works for your compiler or not. You should also take the advice on the forward declaration instead of full include.